# How to get database url from java.sql.Connection?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-string

For given [`Connection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) instance how do I find out url that the `Connection` uses to connect the database ? Is it somewhere in `Properties` returned by [`Connection.getClientInfo()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getClientInfo%28%29) method?

If there you need me to provide clearer description all comments are welcome. Thank you

Answer (score 106, accepted):

[`Connection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) has the `getMetaData()` to return  [`DatabaseMetaData`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) .  [`DatabaseMetaData`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) has the `getURL()` to return the URL for this DBMS.

Comment: Is there way to get it without metadata because if connections fails this code isnt work

Comment: do you think it makes sense that if you cannot connect to the server but can also get the information from the server ? .....

Comment: It dependes on your needs.I need to access only datasource url info in runtime.DirverManagedDatasource has getUrl method and give this info without any server request

Answer (score 30):

I believe you can use the DatabaseMetaData object from the Connection and then get the URL. Try:

```
DatabaseMetaData dmd = connection.getMetaData();
String url = dmd.getURL();
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside the Connection object, you have an object of type DatabaseMetaData, it contains a lot of information about the database.

Lucas de Oliveira gave you a good example of code.

And here is the documentation of the object :
[Interface DatabaseMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider add a link to DatabaseMetaData javadoc.

Answer (score -1):

connection.getClientInfo() has all the details related to connection. It returns a properties object. You can retrieve the value of "password" property to fetch the password that was used for the connection object.

Please let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Welcome. The OP is asking for the database URL, not the password