# is it possible to get the url or server info from java.sql.Connection

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am getting `java.sql.Connection` from `DriverManager.getConnection(...)` and want to know what is the server host+port.
If its relevant, I know its `MYSQL` server.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718952/how-to-get-database-url-from-java-sql-connection

Comment: you are right, didn't see it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alternatively, you might try `connection.getMetaData()`. This would give you a `DatabaseMetaData` object, from which you could call `getURL()`. [(JavaDoc)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getURL%28%29)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718952/how-to-get-database-url-from-java-sql-connection

Answer (score 1):

You can get the host name and port name in following way :

```
con.getMetaData().getURL()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the provider of the connection, for example with [Commons DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html)

The class `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` has getters as well as setters. [(JavaDoc)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use some other class around the Connection, and fill in the required fields when you still know them:

```
class WrappedConnection {
   public final String host;
   // ...
   public final Connection connection;

   WrappedConnection(Connection connection, String host, String database) {      
      this.connection = connection;
      this.host = host;
      // ...
   }
}
```

If you cannot pass the custom data structure and must pass the Connection instead, use

```
public static final WeakHashMap<Connection, WrappedConnection>
```

From this map you can easily obtain your metadata at any time (`Connection` field is not required in this case)

Comment: This would be a solution targeted for the situation where you have many different database connections. Very often an app only connects to 1 or 2 databases in its lifetime, which would make a Map of Connections a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 0):

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, username,
                    pass);
DatabaseMetaData metaData = con.getMetaData();
String url = metaData.getURL();
```

This "url" will include your hostname and portname like jdbc:mysql://myhost:3306/mySchema