# Get the connected mysql database name (JDBC)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

How can get the name of the database name from connection object

```
try {
    this.ds = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/amger");
} catch (NamingException ne) {
}
Connection conObj = ds.getConnection();
```

How do I get that Database name from con

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718952/how-to-get-database-url-from-java-sql-connection

Comment: @almasshaikh "How to get database url from java.sql.Connection?" can never be the same as Database Name

Comment: idea is from url can you get the database name?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Probably the most straightforward way to get the database name from the JDBC Connection object itself is via the `getCatalog()` method:

[Connection#getCatalog()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getCatalog())

However, as Konstantin pointed out in his comment below, that value will not change if the current MySQL database is changed by issuing a `USE dbname` statement.

`getCatalog()` might still be useful in an application that

- does not change databases, or
- does things "The JDBC Way" by using `setCatalog()` to change the current database,

but for MySQL, using `SELECT DATABASE()` appears to be safer overall.

Note also that this potential discrepancy between `getCatalog()` and the actual current database depends on the behaviour of the particular JDBC driver. Out of curiosity I tried something similar with the Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server and `.getCatalog()` was indeed aware of the change to the current database immediately after running a `USE dbname` statement. That is, the code

```java
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:52865;"
        + "databaseName=myDb;" + "integratedSecurity=true";
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl)) {
    System.out.println(String.format(
            "getCatalog() returns: %s", 
            con.getCatalog()));
    try (Statement s = con.createStatement()) {
        System.out.println("           Executing: USE master");
        s.execute("USE master");
    }
    System.out.println(String.format(
            "getCatalog() returns: %s", 
            con.getCatalog()));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

produced the following results:

```
getCatalog() returns: myDb
           Executing: USE master
getCatalog() returns: master
```

Comment: @Gord Thompson, I agree with you. Credits to Konstantin V. Salikhov for his highlight. I feel more comfortable with  Konstantin V. Salikhov approach (SELECT DATABASE()) especially for MySQL specific solution. But as you rightfully say "does things "The JDBC Way" "; Connection#getCatalog() will be more acceptable for portability which is one of Java strong points.

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov That is one of the reasons the JDBC api doc explicitly says not to use database commands (like `USE`) if there is a JDBC equivalent (`setCatalog`).

Comment: The implementations for DatabaseMetaData and Connection classes across databases are unfortunately inconsistent. MySQL "schema" name is null for "getSchema()" when a schema-name is required for DatabaseMetaData related operations (like getPrimaryKeys()) yet getCatalog() works (and can be used as the schema-name). Unfortunately this is not true consistently for Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that DB is Mysql you could just perform `SELECT DATABASE()` on your connection and read the resulset with current database name in it.

Here is [description](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_database) of DATABASE function.

Comment: you mentioned "If you know that DB is Mysql". What made you say that?

Comment: I appreciate your input and pointer to the issue that is assoiciated with @Gord Thompson approach. Your solution is the best for best when it comes to mysql. I am only accepting Gord Thompson for portability reasons, though I am aware of the its possible side effect. Thanks alot brother

Comment: You're welcome. I've mentioned 'If you know that DB is Mysql' because just any RDBMS can be connected to the JDBC datasource, but your particular question had tag mysql in it and DATABASE() is mysql-specific function. I've thought this solution might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you used url as "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"

Then do the following:

```
DatabaseMetaData dmd = connection.getMetaData();
String url = dmd.getURL();
System.out.println(url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
```

Comment: That won't work if the database was changed using the `use` command or through the `setCatalog()` JDBC API

Comment: Agreed but i don't think so OP mentioned about the same.

Comment: The challenge here is that while unfortunately DatabaseMetaData and Connection implementations are inconsistently implemented across DB drivers (MySQL and Oracle for example), the whole point of JDBC (and more related to OP question) is to make it abstract (and yet work)... unfortunately for meta-data ... it just does not work consistently - some combination of logic with getSchema(), getCatalog() and maybe even getUserName() is required.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
System.out.println(connection.getMetaData().getURL());
```

- Paste the output in notepad
- search the value for 'databaseName=yourDBName'