# Is there a way to get the name of a running database?

Tags: java, oracle, postgresql

I'm working on Java with an application that persists in Oracle and PostgreSQL (not at the same time). I'd like to get the type of the database that is currently running because I need to work in a different way depending on whether it's oracle or it's Postgresql.

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26441303/get-the-connected-mysql-database-name-jdbc

Comment: @DanIonescu that question answer database name and not the DBMS name that stores the data which is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: You know in which db you are running, because you most probably invoked different jdbc drivers ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the connected mysql database name (JDBC)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26441303/get-the-connected-mysql-database-name-jdbc)

Comment: @OldProgrammer I disagree with the dupe. OP wants to know the DBMS name, not the DB name.

Comment: You could also try: [Connection#getClientInfo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getClientInfo--) or [Connection#getMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getMetaData--)

Comment: I'd like to get an "oracle" or a "postgres" or something similiar. I need to check this because I have to store a truncated value in Oracle (because I have a varchar2 restriction) and a non-truncated value for Postgresql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JDBC API should help: [getDatabaseProductName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getDatabaseProductName()). There are other methods as well that allow to get the product version and the driver name and its version.