# Passing jdbc connection to spark read

Tags: java, apache-spark, jdbc

I have an sql script which creates temp tables valid for only that session. Now after running the script, I am trying to read data from the table through spark and then process it. Below is the code I have code for spark read.

```
sparkSession.read().format("jdbc").option("url", 
jdbcURL).option("dbtable", tableOrQuery).option("user", 
userName).option("password", password)
      .option("driver", driverName).load();
```

Now I need to pass the jdbc connection I created so that spark can read data in the same session. Is this possible ?

Comment: Incidentally I answered [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54417010/10938362) not so long ago - TL;DR; there can be no such option whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot pass jdbc connection to spark. It will manage JDBC connection by itself.

[JdbcRelationProvider Create Connection](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JdbcRelationProvider.scala#L48)

[JdbcUtils connect](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JdbcUtils.scala#L64)

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any suggestions what I can do instead ?

Comment: You can get connection metadata and build Spark URL according to it, solution is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718952/how-to-get-database-url-from-java-sql-connection